# how to access the list of received sms for iphone?

Tags: iphone

me if possible way is there menas.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no API to get access to the user's SMS/MMS library.

Comment: sending sms possible means, why apple restricted to access received SMS list. I also try to receive the sms through coding

Comment: Probably because of the same reason you don't have access to the user's call history and emails: privacy.